# How to format data.frame suitable for ggplot from pairwise.t.test output

Tags: r, ggplot2, dataframe

My df

```
    df <- data.frame(
    measurement = runif(120, min=1, max=25),    
    group = rep(c("A","B","C","D"), each=3, times=10)
)
```

I put results into a data.frame

```
   ttest_results <- as.data.frame(pairwise.t.test(df$measurement, df$group)$p.value)
```

How I can format df suitable for plotting a ggplot matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to reshape your data using the Hadley universe, namely `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
ttest_results %>% 
  add_rownames("Group.1") %>% 
  gather("Group.2", "value", -Group.1) %>%
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Group.1, Group.2, fill = value)) +
  geom_tile(height = .7, width = .7)
```